# Left join two DataFrames in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to perform a left join on two Spark DataFrames:

The left DataFrame is of the form:

```
Time1                   Ticker  
2015-02-17 14:30:01     AAPL
2015-02-17 14:30:02     AAPL
...                     ...
2015-02-17 15:01:00     AAPL
...                     ...
2015-02-17 14:30:01     GOOG
2015-02-17 14:30:02     GOOG
...                     ...
2015-02-17 15:01:00     GOOG
```

The right DataFrame is of the form:

```
Time2                   AAPL     GOOG
2015-02-17 14:30:01     100.2    700.1
2015-02-17 14:30:02     100.3    700.1
...                     ...      ...
2015-02-17 15:01:00     99.9     699.8
```

And I want the new joined DataFrame looks like:

```
Time1                   Ticker  Price  lag_1_min_Price
2015-02-17 14:30:01     AAPL    100.2  ...
2015-02-17 14:30:02     AAPL    100.3  ...
...                     ...     ...    ...
2015-02-17 15:01:00     AAPL    99.9   ...
...                     ...     ...    ...
2015-02-17 14:30:01     GOOG    700.1  ...
2015-02-17 14:30:02     GOOG    700.1  ...
...                     ...     ...    ...
2015-02-17 15:01:00     GOOG    699.8  ...
```

Note:

- `Time1` is **not** a subset or superset of `Time2`, `NaN` is acceptable.
- The `lag_1_min_Price` will contain the value of the corresponding `Ticker` with `Time1`-`Time2` = 1 minute.

My intuition is to reshape the right DataFrame, i.e. to merge stock stickers into one column (but I don't know how to do that). Moreover, what would be the most efficient way to join the `lag_1_min_Price` column?

Comment: What should the lag_1_min_Price column contain?

Comment: @jtoberon The `lag_1_min_Price` will contain the value of the corresponding `Ticker` with `Time1`-`Time2` = 1 minute.